# Do high-end video cards consume more power during regular PC usage?

Tags: graphics-card, power, computer-building, gaming

For things like coding and web browsing, does a high-end GPU ([NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-660ti/specifications)) consume more power than a low/mid-range GPU ([NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9800gt/specifications))?

The reason I ask is because the 9800 card I have takes no extra power cables, while the 660 ti requires two 6 pin cables.

Comment: I recall seeing charts that show overall higher power consumption by more powerful GPUs for similar tasks.  Makes sense, more transistors and circuitry, even at idle, will use some electrical power.

Comment: I believe the issue here is that the 660 Ti is actually the mid-range product in a 6xx range of cards, whilst the 9800 GT was a higher-range card at the time of its production. I would therefore expect the 9800 to use more power for every task, due to its older manufacturing process, as Louis states, and because it will have more heat generating, performance related features (greater transistor count relative to manufacturing process).

Comment: Depends on the GPU. AMD has ZeroCore Power Technology which shuts down the GPU when the display is off to minimize power consumption. Newer GPUs have other power management technologies which keep power consumption to a minimum under light loads.

Answer (score 5):

Because of smaller manufacturing process sizes, and more power saving features, when comparing GPUs of different generations it wouldn't be surprising the newer generation consumed less power than an older generation card during regular usage.

In the case of the GTX 660 Ti during normal desktop usage (coding, watching 1080p videos on YouTube, etc) it consumes 10-14% of the 150W TDP, which I figure is about 15-21W. For the version of the 9800 GT you linked to, at 105W it would have to achieve 80% an power savings to get there.